# How to dynamically switch disabled=true/false of an input text inside Ember Component?

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember component that I want to dynamically disable/ enable. Initially I have:

```
//template.emblem
= input type="text" disabled=true placeholder="Account Number" class="form-control"
```

When I have `disabled=false`, it enables the button again. Now I want to make it dynamic. I thought of creating a simple function that returns true or false inside `component.js`:

```
//component.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  ...
    disableButton(){
    return true
  },

//template.emblem
  = input type="text" disabled=disableButton placeholder="Account Number" class="form-control"
```

This disables it. However, when I switch `disableButton` to `return false`, it is still disabled.

How can I connect the `disabled` to a function/ property inside `component.js`?

The template.emblem and component.js folder hierarchy is:

```
components
  |-my-awesome-component
    |- template.emblem
    |- component.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a property on your component.js and bind it to "disabled" on the input tag in your template. Then you can call the action with your button and set the property to true or false using this.set().

```
//component.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  disableButton: false,

  actions: {
    disableButton(){
      this.set('disableButton', true);
    }
  }
});

//template.hbs
<button {{action 'disableButton'}}>Click me</button>

{{input type="text" placeholder="Account Number" class="form-control" disabled=disableButton}}
```

Comment: Note: you can also toggle the property with `this.toggleProperty('disableButton');`

Comment: I would very much agree with [toggleProperty](https://www.emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#method_toggleProperty) as it will allow you to disable/enable input with same button. Also this is the ember way of handling booleans inside of ember objects.

Comment: If you plan to "toggle" between true and false, toggleProperty is best. But if you only want the button to "disable" the field, set the value true.